# Bootstrap 4 columns center vertically and keeping same height

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I'm having an issue with bootstrap 4 columns height and vertical alignment.
Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ssj1yg4/1/) with the problem.

i need to design a layout with items, in desktop they're all on the same row, on mobile we get two rows. All of that is encountered with borders.

The problem is that i can't manage to keep the columns's height when i want to vertically center their content.
Without classes added the columns have the same heights but the content is centered to the top. After searches i found the `align-items-center` that center my columns but the height doesnt remain.
Which breaks my border layout.

I tried also to add the `my-auto`, `align-self-center` classes but with no success.

```css
.why-choose-warranty {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f5f3ef;
  color: #11155e;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.why-choose-warranty .row {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.why-choose-warranty .row div {
  justify-content: center;
}


/* Small screens (mobiles) */

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .why-choose-warranty .row {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: .5rem;
  }
  .why-choose-warranty img {
    max-width: 40%;
    max-height: 40%;
  }
  .why-choose-warranty .row div:nth-child(1),
  .why-choose-warranty .row div:nth-child(2) {
    border-right: 1px solid #d7d5d1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d7d5d1;
  }
  .why-choose-warranty .row div:nth-child(3) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d7d5d1;
  }
  .why-choose-warranty .row div:nth-child(4),
  .why-choose-warranty .row div:nth-child(5) {
    border-right: 1px solid #d7d5d1;
  }
}


/* Big screens (desktops) */

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .why-choose-warranty img {
    max-width: 60%;
    max-height: 60%;
  }
  .why-choose-warranty .row div {
    border-right: 1px solid #d7d5d1;
  }
  .why-choose-warranty .row div:last-child {
    border-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="why-choose-warranty">
  <div class="row col-12 col-lg-10 m-auto align-items-center">
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-2">
      <p class="text-center font-weight-bold">Test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-2">
      <p class="text-center font-weight-bold">Test<br /><br />Test TEST</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-2">
      <p class="text-center font-weight-bold">TEST TEST</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-2">
      <p class="text-center font-weight-bold">TEST</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-2">
      <p class="text-center font-weight-bold">TEST <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />TEST</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-2">
      <p class="text-center font-weight-bold">TEST</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone figured out this problem ? Or can help me figure it out ?

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: Try using classes like col-md-# (for tablet) and col-sm-#  (for mobile). This should work. Reference: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#column-resets

Comment: col-sm is replaced by col in my case, and col-md by col-lg. So its not a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

1. Remove `align-items-center` class from your *row* element
2. Add `align-items-center` and `d-flex` classes to each of your `.why-choose-warranty .row div` or add this to the style:

   ```
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   ```

See demo below:

```css
.why-choose-warranty {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f5f3ef;
  color: #11155e;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.why-choose-warranty .row {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.why-choose-warranty .row div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* Small screens (mobiles) */

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .why-choose-warranty .row {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: .5rem;
  }
  .why-choose-warranty img {
    max-width: 40%;
    max-height: 40%;
  }
  .why-choose-warranty .row div:nth-child(1),
  .why-choose-warranty .row div:nth-child(2) {
    border-right: 1px solid #d7d5d1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d7d5d1;
  }
  .why-choose-warranty .row div:nth-child(3) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d7d5d1;
  }
  .why-choose-warranty .row div:nth-child(4),
  .why-choose-warranty .row div:nth-child(5) {
    border-right: 1px solid #d7d5d1;
  }
}


/* Big screens (desktops) */

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .why-choose-warranty img {
    max-width: 60%;
    max-height: 60%;
  }
  .why-choose-warranty .row div {
    border-right: 1px solid #d7d5d1;
  }
  .why-choose-warranty .row div:last-child {
    border-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="why-choose-warranty">
  <div class="row col-12 col-lg-10 m-auto">
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-2">
      <p class="text-center font-weight-bold">Test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-2">
      <p class="text-center font-weight-bold">Test<br /><br />Test TEST</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-2">
      <p class="text-center font-weight-bold">TEST TEST</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-2">
      <p class="text-center font-weight-bold">TEST</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-2">
      <p class="text-center font-weight-bold">TEST <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />TEST</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-2">
      <p class="text-center font-weight-bold">TEST</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer solves my problem, or at least put me in the right direction. Adding the css `display: flex; align-items: center;` on the element center them vertically while keeping the same height.

I had another small problem that i have two elements in the div and i want them to be one on top of the other.
So i had to add an extra div with the d-inline-block class.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You add `d-flex` and remove `align-items-center` on

- `<div class="row col-12 col-lg-10 m-auto d-flex">`

and add `d-flex align-items-center` to your

- `<div class="col-4 col-lg-2 d-flex align-items-center">`

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ssj1yg4/3/)

```css
.why-choose-warranty{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f5f3ef;
  color: #11155e;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.why-choose-warranty .row{
  padding: 1rem;
}
.why-choose-warranty .row div{
  justify-content: center;
}

/* Small screens (mobiles) */
@media screen and (max-width: 992px){
  .why-choose-warranty .row{
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: .5rem;
  }
  .why-choose-warranty img{
    max-width: 40%;
    max-height: 40%;
  }
  .why-choose-warranty .row div:nth-child(1), .why-choose-warranty .row div:nth-child(2){
    border-right: 1px solid #d7d5d1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d7d5d1;
  }
  .why-choose-warranty .row div:nth-child(3){
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d7d5d1;
  }
  .why-choose-warranty .row div:nth-child(4), .why-choose-warranty .row div:nth-child(5){
    border-right: 1px solid #d7d5d1;
  }
}

/* Big screens (desktops) */
@media screen and (min-width: 992px){
  .why-choose-warranty img{
    max-width: 60%;
    max-height: 60%;
  }
  .why-choose-warranty .row div{
    border-right: 1px solid #d7d5d1;
  }
  .why-choose-warranty .row div:last-child{
    border-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="why-choose-warranty">
  <div class="row col-12 col-lg-10 m-auto d-flex">
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-2 d-flex align-items-center">
      <p class="text-center font-weight-bold">Test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-2 d-flex align-items-center">
      <p class="text-center font-weight-bold">Test
        <br />
        <br />Test TEST</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-2 d-flex align-items-center">
      <p class="text-center font-weight-bold">TEST TEST</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-2 d-flex align-items-center">
      <p class="text-center font-weight-bold">TEST</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-2 d-flex align-items-center">
      <p class="text-center font-weight-bold">TEST
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />TEST</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-2 d-flex align-items-center">
      <p class="text-center font-weight-bold">TEST</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MartinStievenart Thanks. Do note, as done in the  other answer, to create your own `flex rules` is not the way to go, but rather use the built-in classes, which I showed here, or else the whole point using a framework is lost. And on top of that, increase what needs to download more than necessary will make your solution less performant and more to maintain.

Comment: Yeah i used the build-in classes that bootstrap provide.
I try to use them as much as i can when i know them, which become not easy coz there are some for everything :)

Comment: @MartinStievenart Out of curiosity, and as you say you do use the built-in classes, wouldn't it then be more appropriate to accept the answer that actually does use that in its solution?